# Byteoffset not equal to column offset unix file

Tags: unix, vim, byte

I want to get all the lines in file where byte offset is not equal to column offset of line in Unix. How can I do so?

Please help, I not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to list all lines where the number of bytes (representing the characters) is not equal to the number of screen columns (so effectively lines with non-ASCII characters or Tab).

In Vim, this can be done by comparing `strlen()` with `strdisplaywidth()`, iterating with `:global`:

```
:global/^/if strlen(getline('.')) != strdisplaywidth(getline('.')) | number | endif
```

Comment: No.. Several UTF8 character can have one character per byte

Comment: Yes, the ones from 7-bit ASCII, as I've mentioned. Do does this solve your problem?

Comment: Getting error E117: Unknown function: strdisplaywidth
E15: Invalid expression: strlen(getline('.')) != strdisplaywidth(getline('.')) | number | endif

Comment: You need Vim 7.4 (or a fairly recent 7.3 build) for that.